# Draw square and bullet arrow with core graphics

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to draw the following in objective-c? I tried using the image, but It pixelates. So I figured it is best to draw it programatically. Can someone provide me some sample code to achieve this.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CAShapeLayer`and assign it a path describing your shape:

```
- (UIBezierPath *)createBubblePathInFrame:(CGRect) frame{
    CGFloat arrowInset = 10;
    CGFloat arrowHeight = 10;
    CGFloat arrowWidth = 20;

    UIBezierPath *path  = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, arrowHeight)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(arrowInset, arrowHeight)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(arrowInset+arrowWidth/2, 0)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(arrowInset+arrowWidth, arrowHeight)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(frame.size.width, arrowHeight)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, frame.size.height)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, arrowHeight)];
    return path;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
    CAShapeLayer *shapelayer  = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapelayer.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 100);
    shapelayer.path = [self createBubblePathInFrame:shapelayer.bounds].CGPath;
    shapelayer.fillColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    shapelayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    shapelayer.lineWidth = 1;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:shapelayer];
```

Or you can draw it yourself in `drawRect`:

```
[[UIColor grayColor] setFill];
[bezierPath fill];
[[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
[bezierPath stroke];
```

Comment: this answer is better than mine

Comment: What do I do to add content inside this layer/path? or on top of it? I need to place some label and stuff.

Comment: Just create an UIView and add this Layer to it. Then add additional subviews as you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as a triangle view:

```
 @implementation Triangle

 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (self)
     {
         self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
         self.alpha = 0.75;
     }
    return self;
 }


 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
     CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

     CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
     CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));  // top left
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));  // top right
     CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));  // bottom mid
     CGContextClosePath(ctx);

     CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 25.0/255.0, 25.0/255.0, 25.0/255.0, 1.0);
     CGContextFillPath(ctx);
 }

 @end
```

Then just subclass a `UIView` and add an instance of `Triangle` where appropriate (in your case on the top left corner).

For your purpose you also should rotate this triangle 180 degrees as the code above drwas a triangle that points downwards.

Comment: `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

`myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);`